# Eclipse content assist on a remote java file?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, when I edit a remote .java file, content assist does not work.  Why does a java file have to be part of a project to get syntax expansion (for an if/else block, for example) or to use templates? Now, I can understand why it is needed for looking up possible methods and javadoc stuff.  Can't eclipse just recognize that the file has the extension .java and let me do templates I have defined?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For Eclipse Luna, I open a file with  File->Open File from a folder on computer and content assist works.